# Conditional poker probability.

Tags: probability, statistics, poker

In event space for a standard pack of 52 playing cards. Assume there are no wild cards. Consider 5-card hands.

Compute the conditional probability of a straight flush given that the first two cards you are dealt are the 9 and 10 of hearts.

**my guess is 4/(52 C 5) but I am really unsure**

Comment: Any thoughts?  What happens when you try to apply the standard techniques?

Comment: Should say:  In the usual rules of poker, a "straight flush" excludes a Royal Flush, not that this changes the math very much.  But, still, you should indicate whether or not you intend to follow that convention.

Comment: What adjectives might you apply to describe these hands?  Suit, rank, etc.  Such as, a 4 of a kind has 4 card of one rank (how many ranks are there?) and one card not of that rank (how many cards not of that rank are there?).

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right. There are four possibilities for a straight flush. But the total number of possible hands is not $52\choose 5$, because two cards have already been dealt; it is $50\choose 3$.

So the answer is $\dfrac{4}{50\choose 3}$.